# Tell RSpec view spec which route to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, view

I want to spec a view which I use in several contexts.

For the current spec, the view normally is called under `project_boilerplate_copy_path(@project, @boilerplate_copy)` which results in `/projects/123/boilerplatecopies/321/`.

I'm unsure now how to tell the view spec to use that route.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "boilerplates/show", type: :view do
  context 'with findings' do
    it "Doesn't render empty url" do
      assign :boilerplate, create(:boilerplate_copy, findings: [create(:finding, url: nil)])
      render
      expect(rendered).not_to have_selector('.url')
    end
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
Failure/Error: render
ActionView::Template::Error:
  No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"boilerplate_copies", :locale=>:en}
```

I tried fiddling around with `RSpec.describe "boilerplates/show"`, but this didn't work out yet.

Here are my routes:

```
scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|de/ do
  # ...

  resources :projects do
    resources :boilerplate_copies
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb?

Comment: Does the route require a `:project_id`? Is that value being assigned somewhere?

Comment: Added the specific routes.

Answer (score 0):

The failure is occurring while the template is being rendered, as indicated by the message:

```
Failure/Error: render
```

As to why it is failing, my guess is that the template is using a helper to generate a path/url, and the helper is trying to generate a path to `/boilerplate_copies`, based on the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
  No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"boilerplate_copies", :locale=>:en}
```

when it should be generating a path to `/projects/:project_id/boilerplate_copies`, since your `routes.rb` defines a nested resource that requires a `:project_id`. Without seeing the templates it's hard to say more.